# Three.js: modify Objects by Name

Tags: javascript, three.js

How can I access multiple meshes with the same name?

```
var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff }));
mesh1.name = "meshes";
scene.add( mesh1);

var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff }));
mesh2.name = "meshes";
scene.add( mesh2);
```

---

Something like:

```
meshes.position.z = 2;
```

Comment: Your code won't actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the meshes in a two dimensional array indexed by their name. Then you could do:

```
arr["meshes"].forEach(function(obj, idx){
    obj.position.z = 2;
});
```